# SQL Match and Replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have to update a table in my sql server with data from an excel sheet It is a lot of parts I need to update and I need to update two columns in a 12 column table.  What would be the easiest way doing this?

I was thinking access?  I tried to do a SSIS job on the specific two columns but it failed.

Please help and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to import the Excel file into your sql database and then do the update with a simple update statement like his:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Column1 = ExcelImported.Column1,
    Column2 = ExcelImported.Column2
FROM    YourTable 
JOIN    ExcelImported
ON      YourTable.Key = ExcelImported.Key
```

Comment: Can I join on a specific column besides using the primary key?            THANKS! because the excel sheet doesn't have a primary key but the part numbers are identical on both